# useFocusEffect with useEffect randomly returns warning "property of the 'route' object is not supported"

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have this effect which sets a state when leaving a screen. When the state is set to null, it fires a function that closes a bottom sheet (alerts)

```
useFocusEffect(
  React.useCallback(() => {
    return () => {
      setAlert(null);
    };
  }, [setAlert])
```

I **randomly** get this warning when moving to another screen** while the alerts bottom sheet is open**: `Accessing the 'state' property of the 'route' object is not supported. If you want to get the focused route name, use the 'getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute' helper instead: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-options-resolution/#setting-parent-screen-options-based-on-child-navigators-state`

When I disable this `useFocusEffect`, the warning goes away.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://github.com/gorhom/react-native-bottom-sheet/issues/297

Comment: @satya164 thank you!